# Аудит показывает существующий ответ, скрыв его автора

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, аудит

Привет, это я и я [завалил аудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/71489). *Не опять, а снова :)*

На сей раз в очереди **первых сообщений**. У меня были подозрения, что это аудит, посему я оставил тревогу модератору с пояснением, но полагаю, что эта тревога до модератора не дойдёт, *ибо аудит*.

Конкретно эта механика аудита мне кажется несколько странной. Её суть, как я понимаю, в следующем:

- Берётся качественный **заплюсованный и принятый ответ**
- Заменяются упоминания об авторе на **анонима без профиля**
  *(кстати, это не нарушение CC-BY-SA?)*
- Выставляется **ноль голосов**
- Подделывается **время публикации на недавнее**

Но забавно то, что **я видел этот ответ раньше**, я помню, что **он был заплюсован** и был опубликован [уважаемым членом сообщества VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd), посему, я заподозрил, что таким образом кто-то новенький решил срубить репутации, опубликовав точную копию доказанно хорошего ответа, а *(далее следует моё заблуждение)* "система его не показывает, пока ответ не пройдёт через очередь первых сообщений".

Я вижу тут **прямой сценарий для "плохих намерений"**.
Плохо то, что он **прямо следует из механики аудита**.

Следует ли **изменить эту механику** в аудитах, или **вовсе убрать**? Или аудит совершенно прав, схватив меня за руку, а я должен был об этой очереди что-то заранее знать?

*Аудит явно предполагает, что я не знаю его механики и меня застают врасплох,* поэтому "знать механику аудита" я точно не должен.

Comment: Да, я тоже на таком попадался разок на en.so ))

Answer (score 4):

*"Вы слишком много думаете, это вредно"* (с)

> Я вижу тут прямой сценарий для "плохих намерений".
>   Плохо то, что он прямо следует из механики аудита.

Очередь первых сообщений существует для того, чтобы опытные участники помогали новичкам освоиться на сайте. Сами новички в проверках не участвуют и узнать, как проходят аудиты, им неоткуда. Если же вы имели в виду "плохие намеренья" проверяющего (будет пытаться сжульничать в аудитах), так аудитов и не было бы, если бы не было жуликов, набивающих проверки простым кликаньем по одной кнопке. Это первое.

Второе: Проверять в очереди следует **качество** сообщений, а не этическую сторону вопроса. Если это **действительно** окажется вопрос или ответ от новичка-плагиатора - его всегда можно легко [найти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history) после проверки и отправить тревогу уже оттуда. Конечный результат будет тот же, следовательно - ваша проверка свою задачу выполнит.

В текущем виде вы действительно провалили аудит, так как исходили, с точки зрения аудита, из **предположения**, что автор поста - плагиатор, а не **фактов**, видных из **выданной** вам информации. Аудит же не может знать, что этот пост вы уже видели и запомнили автора.

Comment: *узнать, как проходят аудиты, им неоткуда* -- вопрос был о том, что о механике аудитов не должен знать **я, как "опытный участник"**. Аудит же должен проверять **меня**, новичку об аудитах знать вообще необязательно.

Comment: И нет, в очереди первых сообщений **не проверяется качество сообщений новичков**, а принимаются меры, цитирую, "чтобы помочь освоиться на сайте". Если новичок действительно скопировал известный ответ, выдав его за свой, я **помогаю ему освоиться**, немедленно дав ему знать, что у нас такие действия неприемлемы.

Comment: @D-side но нет принципиальной разницы, сделаете вы это из очереди проверок или сразу после неё, результат-то тот же. Аудит же, показывающий реальных авторов постов бесполезен, так как его легко распознать обойти.

Comment: Принципиальной разницы нет, просто это ставит под сомнение надобность аудитов с такой механикой вообще. Да, просто показ авторов постов проблемы не исправит, но это не означает, что существующую механику нужно оставлять как есть.

Comment: @D-side я, например, не знаю, как можно изменить механику аудита, чтобы исключить случаи, подобные вашему. Но знаю, как вы можете изменить свою логику проверок, чтобы не попадать в такие ситуации, потому и оставил этот ответ, чтобы помочь вам.

Comment: Ответ был опубликован "якобы другим человеком", "якобы в другое время", и "якобы это первый ответ человека на сайте". Похоже на факты? Если я подстрою свою логику под аудит, то аудит перестанет исходить из того, что я о нём не знаю, и потеряет смысл. Это не решение, это "костыль", который сработает, но свидетельствует о более глубокой проблеме.

Comment: @D-side я там исправил ответ, почитайте: Из сообщения не следует, что оно уже было опубликовано другим участником, это следует из ваших данных, полученных **вне** аудита. Использовать эти данные, с точки зрения аудита, - жульничество.

Comment: Нет, не жульничество. Выданных аудитом фактов [не всегда достаточно, чтобы сделать вывод](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300234/2076787). Аудит должен удостовериться, что я не делаю решений вслепую/наугад, и на мой взгляд эта механика в этом виде этой задачи не выполняет.

Comment: И я имел в виду **плохие намерения новичка**, не в отношении аудитов, а в отношении накопления репутации, и их в вопросе же и описал: *"срубить репутации, опубликовав точную копию доказанно хорошего ответа"*.